# Парс json файла angular 2

Tags: angular2

Товарищи, подскажите, парсю json ->

```
[
  {"nodename":"192.124.105.55",
   "servicelist":[
      {
         "id":"ec9471ec001c10b9fa286e1f52e39c5dc9485a7c2cfbf55145c26242bb98ec4d",
         "name":"Nginx",
         "status":"Online",
         "servicecontrolled":true
       },
       {
          "id":"f4ca9e0badc6b23e3e36444bd7ee4a9efcd39de8e0bb4cdecb25b5a02ef86ba5",
          "name":"Memcached",
          "status":"Offline",
         "servicecontrolled":true        
       },
        {
          "id":"0a4bf3b5bb5f47ece9284052389ae02f6c9dba989ca34086a30e049ee3d8eb47",
          "name":"Celery",
          "status":"Offline",
         "servicecontrolled":true
         }
     ],
  "storagelist":
  [
     {
       "mountpoint":"/",
       "total":188,
       "used":28,
       "free":161
    },
   {
       "mountpoint":"/boot",
       "total":235,
       "used":106,
       "free":129
     }
  ],
 "system":
 {
      "memory":
     {
        "total":33673834496,
        "used":14725959680,
        "free":18947874816,
        "actualfree":24221499392,
        "actualused":9452335104,
        "swaptotal":34296819712,
        "swapused":0,
        "swapfree":34296819712
       },
      "uptime":" 4:09",
       "loadaverage":"0.91 0.49 0.54",
       "cpu":
              {
                   "vendor":"GenuineIntel",
                   "family":"6",
                   "model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz",
                   "rate":"2399.971",
                   "numofcores":2
               }
   }
 },
   {"nodename":"192.124.105.58",
     "servicelist":[
       {"id":"428d3cc1d4d7218d6b9d1a80152179fac0aba40e2eee5525befe1355919db5e6",
        "name":"Nginx",
        "status":"Online"
        },
        {
          "id":"9f71381ff2e2181b4dde841e85d7d29af33fc2bd1929092aedf237d124ae75e0",
          "name":"Memcached",
          "status":"Online"
        },
        {
          "id":"c7dc289c490b8087d47971a45d545fcbbf7f425b1087179ae4a05c585c859302",
          "name":"gunicorn",
          "status":"Online"
         },
         {
           "id":"a96c90d2423c4e300d8d1d83b2e4dfdd70af9ca0ae91bdba35a66dd9ffa2f572",
           "name":"test",
           "status":"Offline"
          }
        ],
        "storagelist": [],
        "system":
         {
              "memory":
              {
                   "total":12425734566,
                   "used":4725959680,
                  "free":8947874816,
                  "actualfree":4221499392,
                 "actualused":452335104,
                 "swaptotal":4296819712,
                 "swapused":0,
                 "swapfree":4296819712
               },
               "uptime":" 12 days,  4:09",
               "loadaverage":"0.00 0.00 0.00",
              "cpu":
              {
                   "vendor":"GenuineIntel",
                   "family":"6",
                   "model":"Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz",
                   "rate":"2399.971",
                   "numofcores":4
               }
             }
   }
]
```

все бы ничего, но вот не получается спарсить вот этот момент

```
"system": {
  "memory": {
    "total": 12425734566,
    "used": 4725959680,
    "free": 8947874816,
    "actualfree": 4221499392,
    "actualused": 452335104,
    "swaptotal": 4296819712,
    "swapused": 0,
    "swapfree": 4296819712
  },
```

Вот мой html ->

```
<h1> Мониторинг сервисов (M.S.A) </h1>
<table class="table table-bordered" *ngFor="let list of lists">
<caption>{{ list.nodename }}</caption>
<thead>
   <tr>
       <th>Название сервиса</th>
       <th></th>
       <th>Операции</th>  
       <th>Статус</th>   
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.servicelist">
            <td> {{ service_rec.name }} </td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                 <span [style.background-color]="service_rec.status == 'Online' ? 'green' : 'red'"
                 class="label label-default">
                 {{ service_rec.status }}
                 </span>
            </td>      
        </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Файловая система</th>
              <th>Всего</th>
              <th>Использовано</th>
              <th>Доступно</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let service_rec of list.storagelist">
              <td> {{ service_rec.mountpoint }} </td>
              <td> {{ service_rec.total | byteFormat }} </td>
              <td> {{ service_rec.used | byteFormat }} </td>
              <td> {{ service_rec.free | byteFormat }} </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Общая память</th>
                <th>Общая используемая память</th>
                <th>Свободная память</th>
                <th>Используемая память размера подкачки</th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: в чем проблема то? Почему не получается? Не вижу в коде обращение к объекту

Comment: @zhenyab я не знаю как к нему обращаться, собственно поэтому и задаю вопрос

Comment: Покажите хоть код контроллера что ли. Откуда вы получаете эти данные? Что конкретно, вообще говоря, у вас не получается?